# Error al intentar sacar un caracter de una variable

Tags: java, array, string, variables

Mi intención es que el programa muestre por pantalla un mensaje por cada carácter de la frase que yo introduzco. Al nombrar la variable y especificar que muestre un carácter en concreto me salta el error, concretamente en "frase[i]"

```
package preguntas;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class cadenaletras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escribe una frase");
        int longitud = frase.length();
        

        for(int i=0; i < longitud ; i++){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,frase[i]);
        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay q tener en cuenta que un String no se puede recorrer como si fuera un arreglo.

Para esto te recomendaría usar substring de la siguiente manera.

```
for(int i=0; i < longitud ; i++){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,frase.substring(i,i+1));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

A diferencia de Javascript, en Java no puedes acceder a un caracter que forma parte de un String usando la misma notación que se usaría con un array.

Tienes dos formas de acceder:

```
String s= "abc";
char c = s.charAt(0) //devuelve un char, no un String
```

o

```
char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
char sc = charArray[0];
```

Pero si necesitas Strings para poder pasar cada carácter a tu *Dialog*, puedes generar un array de Strings de un único caracter:

```
String[] caracteres= frase.split("");

for(int i=0; i < caracteres.length ; i++){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,caracteres[i]);
}
```